# Use generators to generate (p,1-p) pairs

Tags: python

What I want to do is:

```
my_list = []
for i in range(10):
   p = random.random()
   my_list.append( (p,1-p) )
```

I am trying to do the same thing with generators. I tried the following:

```
my_list = [ (random.random(), 1-random.random()) for i in range(10) ]
```

which does not work as expected since it is calling `random.random()` twice, which produces different results.

How can I do it using generator expressions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use creator-function:

```
def generate_pair(p):
    return (p, 1-p)

my_list = [ generate_pair(random.random()) for i in range(10) ]
```

or use nested generators:

```
random_numbers = (random.random() for i in range(10))
my_list = [ (p, p-1) for p in random_numbers ]
```

Comment: It actually makes sense. Thanks.